# onclick to run method in home controller and reload index view with new data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

my knowledge with JS is shaky so please help me.
I have index view where some data is loaded and displayed like this:

```
@model List<PolicyModel> 
@foreach (var item in Model){ #table_here }
```

I have a method in Home controller to insert new value and return new list
`public List<PolicyModel> InsertPolicy(){ return NewListOfPolicies}`
I have a button to insert new data
`<input class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="button" value="Submit Request" onclick="return InsertPolicy()" />`
Help me to write jquery or ajax function InsertPolicy() to load new data into index view. It can stay not refreshed.

Comment: If you're more familiar with C# you might want to use Blazor: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/install  For javascript/ajax, your question is pretty broad and you'd really want to learn the language first, then maybe learn jQuery and then about ajax calls.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.